# Update row index when all columns of the next row ara NaN in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, pdf, tabula

I have a Pandas DataFrame extracted from a PDF with [tabula-py](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py).

The PDF is like this:

```
+--------------+--------+-------+
|     name     | letter | value |
+--------------+--------+-------+
| A short name | a      |     1 |
+-------------------------------+
| Another      | b      |     2 |
+-------------------------------+
| A very large | c      |     3 |
| name         |        |       |
+-------------------------------+
| other one    | d      |     4 |
+-------------------------------+
| My name is   | e      |     5 |
| big          |        |       |
+--------------+--------+-------+
```

As you can see `A very large name` has a line break and, as the original pdf does not have borders, a row with `['name', NaN, NaN]` and another with `['A very large', 'c', 3]` are created in the DataFrame, when I want only a sigle one with content: `['A very large name', 'c', 3]`.

Same happens with `My name is big`

As this happens for several rows which I'm trying to achieve is concatenate the content of the `name` cell with the previous one when the rest of the cells in the row are `NaN`. Then delete the NaN rows.

But any other strategy that obtain the same result is welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "name": ["A short name", "Another", "A very large", "name", "other one", "My name is", "big"],
    "letter": ["a", "b", "c", np.NaN, "d", "e", np.NaN],
    "value": [1, 2, 3, np.NaN, 4, 5, np.NaN],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_expected = {
    "name": ["A short name", "Another", "A very large name", "other one", "My name is big"],
    "letter": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
}

df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data_expected)
```

I'm trying code like this, but is not working

```
# Not works and not very `pandastonic`
nan_indexes = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis='columns')].index 
df.loc[nan_indexes - 1, "name"] = df.loc[nan_indexes - 1, "name"].str.cat(df.loc[nan_indexes, "name"], ' ')

# remove NaN rows
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with `groupby.agg` with `join` or `first` depending on the columns. the groups are created with checking where it is `notna` in the column letter and value and `cumsum`.

```
print (df.groupby(df[['letter', 'value']].notna().any(1).cumsum())
         .agg({'name': ' '.join, 'letter':'first', 'value':'first'})
      )
                name letter  value
1       A short name      a    1.0
2            Another      b    2.0
3  A very large name      c    3.0
4          other one      d    4.0
5     My name is big      e    5.0
```